# How to stop UITableView from update contentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

When `reloadData` gets called, it seems that the `UITableView` recalculate its `contentSize` automatically so that the content will fit (see screenshot of the call stack in `Xcode`). How do I stop that?

I want to have the `contentSize` to be bigger than its content in some cases, when the table is partly obscured. But any changes of the `contentSize` will disappear after reloading.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the contentSize of UITableView after every "reloadData" call, you can do this :

```
[self.tableView reloadData];

self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.contentSize.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height < 44 ? 150/*any desired value you like*/ :self.tableView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: The simplest solution is almost always the best! :) This will definitely solve the problem. However I chose to do it in another way (see my own answer).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `contentInset` instead, like this:

```
float extraSpaceAtTheBottom = 50;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, extraSpaceAtTheBottom, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a layout constraint for height on the tableView.

Comment: Can you give an example, please?